# Java - networking - Best Practice - mixed synchronous / asynchronous commands

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm developing a small client-server program in Java.

The client and the server are connected over one tcp-connection. Most parts of the communication are asynchronous (can happen at any time) but some parts I want to be synchronous (like ACKs for a sent command).

I use a Thread that reads commands from the socket's InputStream and raises an onCommand() event. The Command itself is progressed by the Command-Design-Pattern.

What would be a best-practice approach (Java), to enable waiting for an ACK without missing other, commands that could appear at the same time?

```
con.sendPacket(new Packet("ABC"));
// wait for ABC_ACK
```

**edit1**

Think of it like an FTP-Connection but that both data and control-commands are on the same connection. I want to catch the response to a control-command, while data-flow in the background is running.

**edit2**

Everything is sent in blocks to enable multiple (different) transmissons over the same TCP-Connection (multiplexing)

```
Block:
1 byte - block's type
2 byte - block's payload length
n byte - block's paylod
```

Comment: so after you have sent the packet, you want the method to **block** until it receives the ACK packet?

Comment: you want to send "ABC" and wait for the ack, but also be able to send "EFG" whithout having to delay because of the ABC_ACK?

Comment: yes to both. i have control-commands (like the ABC) and data-flow on the same connection. the reading thread reads both of them. so my problem is, how to "deliver" the ABC_ACK from the reading thread, to the (blocking) method, that sent the ABC.

Comment: You don't need ACKs for TCP commands. It takes care of this for you. Why are you mucking about with acknowledgement?

Comment: To me this sounds more as multiplexing than asynchronous. 2 data streams at the same time on a connection would probably require sending data in blocks, each response block identified with the request id. Like TCP/IP does :)

Comment: i need the ack because the command could fail on the other side (wrong parameters, something already in use, ...). I'm sending command-packets over the tcp-stream. Each "packet" begins with 1 byte describing it's type (data, control, ...), followed by 2 bytes for it's length, followed by the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, you need a registry of blocked threads (or better, the locks on which they are waiting), keyed with some identifier which will be sent by the remote side.

For asynchronous operation, you simply sent the message and proceed.

For synchronous operation, after sending the message, your sending thread (or the thread which initiated this) create a lock object, adds this with some key to the registry and then waits on the lock until notified.

The reading thread, when it receives some answer, looks in the registry for the lock object, adds the answer to it, and calls `notify()`. Then it goes reading the next input.

The hard work here is the proper synchronization to avoid dead locks as well as missing a notification (because it comes back before we added ourself to the registry).

I did something like this when I implemented the remote method calling protocol for our [Fencing](http://www.fencing-game.de/)-applet. In principle RMI works the same way, just without the asynchronous messages.

Comment: So I would do something like: `reader.waitForCmd("ABC_ACK")` which internally adds something to a list, waits and is notified (resumed) when the ABC_ACK arrived via the reading-thread?

Comment: Yes, someone like this. I would use a map instead of a list (to allow efficient retrieval of the right lock even if lots of threads are waiting), though.

Comment: One question to clarify: Am I right to assume, that I start a `new Thread()` (the writing thread) just for the purpose of sending a synchronous request? If so, how do I get the response in the sending thread? As far as I understood I don't even wait for a response there, but the lock object (which I assume is of the response object type?) is simply "filled" through the reference in the registry by the reading thread?

Comment: Further:
1. Wouldn't that require downcasting? E.g. If I choose the registry to be `Map<Object, long> locksAndRequestIdsMap;`, then I either need to maintain zillions of different registries (types) or always downcast `Object` in the sending thread that is notified (resumed).
2. When do I remove the lock-object / response object from the registry?

If I'm getting something totally wrong, do you have an example on hand?

Comment: @cobby As I understand "synchronous", you don't want to continue with the execution in the thread which did this until the answer comes. So no need to create a new thread, as you already are in one.
The lock object can either be a normal object (like just `new Object()`) where we can use `.wait()` and `.notify()`, or we can use specialized lock objects from java.util.concurrent.locks.  And the registry would be e.g. `Map<Long, Object>`, mapping from a request ID to the corresponding lock.

Comment: About casting: If your responses are of different types, you'll somehow figure out what it is. I hope the waiting threads know what kind of response they expect, and can parse the response back into the correct type.

Comment: Wait, at what point would you create the writing and reading threads? I thought I'd have one thread where the main program runs and also the socket's input stream is read. And if I need to make a synchronous request, then I'd need to do this in a separate thread. Would you recommend another setup? Second, wouldn't the reading thread not simply modify/add the reponse to the lock object and the writing thread `registry.get()` the reponse from there (basically lock equals response)? So, if my lock object is of some other type than string, this would require casting, rather than parsing?

Answer (score 1):

@Paulo's solution is one I have used before. However, there may be a simpler solution.

Say you don't have a background thread reading results in the connection.  What you can do instead do is use the current thread to read any results.

```
// Asynchronous call
conn.sendMessage("Async-request");
// server sends no reply.

// Synchronous call.
conn.sendMessage("Sync-request");
String reply = conn.readMessage();
```

Comment: yeah, i used your approach before, but this only works if i know what packet will appear next. if there is a background-data-flow, the next packet could be a data packet and not the ACK i'm waiting for. that's my problem. the background thread mainly handles the data-packets as this is easy and does not need to be synchronized.

Comment: I would use a separate connection for background data flow, if you have any.  The other option is to have readMessage wait until it read a matching requestId. You could have the send messages also check for data to be read.  This is only useful if to are periodically check the stream and not using blocking IO.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Since you referred to Paulo's answer (and seem to do it in a similar way), I'd also like to know your opinion on my comments to his answer :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Creating two sockets per client (one for dataflow in the background and one for the synchronous calls) won't work. How would the server know that the next two socket connections belong the same client and not two different ones?

Comment: @cobby the client can send a UUID or login on connection. This might be useful for tracking a client if it loses a connection and reconnects.

Comment: @cobby it's only a suggestion and it depends on the use case whether this makes things easier or more complicated.